# Unresolved dependencies when installing AceStream

Tags: debian, apt

I'm using ''Debian GNU/Linux stretch/sid''.

I'm trying to install AceStream, following [these](http://wiki.acestream.org/wiki/index.php/Streaming/en) steps.

But when I added this line to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://repo.acestream.org/debian/ sid main
```

and got the public key like this:

```
sudo wget -O - http://repo.acestream.org/keys/acestream.public.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

the attempt to `apt-get install acestream-engine` failed with the following result:

```
Following packages have unresolved dependencies:
 acestream-engine : Requires: python2.7-apsw but cannot be installed
```

(this is translated from my language, not the exact result)

I tried googling `python2.7-apsw`, but it is some kind of [virtual package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/python-apsw) and I'm not sure how to deal with this

Comment: `apt-get install python-apsw`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Submit a bug report to acestream, their `acestream-engine` package is broken.  `python2.7-apsw` does not exist in debian sid.  the package they should be depending upon is called `python-apsw`.

Alternatively (or additionally), you can use the debian `equivs` package to build a dummy `python2.7-apsw` package that has no contents but depends on `python-apsw`

```
Package: equivs
Description-en: Circumvent Debian package dependencies
 This package provides a tool to create trivial Debian packages.
 Typically these packages contain only dependency information, but they
 can also include normal installed files like other packages do.
 .
 One use for this is to create a metapackage: a package whose sole
 purpose is to declare dependencies and conflicts on other packages so
 that these will be automatically installed, upgraded, or removed.
 .
 Another use is to circumvent dependency checking: by letting dpkg
 think a particular package name and version is installed when it
 isn't, you can work around bugs in other packages' dependencies.
 (Please do still file such bugs, though.)
```

Comment: @Jytug Modifying the packaging and rebuilding the package may also be an option, assuming they make the packaging available.